# My website change automatically lenguage in wordpress

Tags: language

how are you?
I don't know why when I change the page on my website automatically change the language.
For example: I start on the home page (in English), when I go to another page as  "Services ", the page loads in Spanish (and I need to go to the top menu of the page, to select the English option to change the language of this page). The page is datrick.com (You can see it, starting in English and then going to  "Services " and see how it change). the page was made in wordpress. i use a polylang plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The service links on your front page point to the spanish version of your site. For example Market Research has the link https://datrick.com/investigacion-de-mercado/. If you want it to direct to the english version, change the link accordingly (i.e. https://datrick.com/en/market-research/).

Comment: hi @Antii Koskinen I tried, but I don't know where I can change it. Because in WordPress customize I can put only one link (but I want to put both, if you start in Spanish... Redirect to pages in Spanish, and if you start in English.. Redirect to English).And look at the menu above, it doesn't change